# Program that tracks mouse coordinates and allows to draw lines in a window

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, drawing, mouseevent

The program should do the following:

1. Open a window. Get the Location of the mouse in the Window (x and y coordinates) and set these as the title of the window.
2. If you click and hold the left mouse button you should be able to draw a line.

The problem is when I run the program no. 1 works, but not no. 2. Upon resizing the Window the coordinates freeze, but I can draw lines.

Hope someone can help with this.

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JPanel {

    private Point lastPoint;


    public Main() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                lastPoint = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        });
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                Graphics g = getGraphics();
                g.drawLine(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y, e.getX(), e.getY());
                lastPoint = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                g.dispose();
            }
        });
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Main(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                int x = e.getX();
                int y = e.getY();
                String xstring = String.valueOf(x);
                String ystring = String.valueOf(y);
                frame.setTitle(xstring + ", " +  ystring);
        }
        });
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the following to the MouseMotionAdapter you can see how your title is adapted while you drag the mouse.
Perhaps you can contionue from there.

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
  int x = e.getX();
  int y = e.getY();
  String xstring = String.valueOf(x);
  String ystring = String.valueOf(y);
  frame.setTitle("dragged - " + xstring + ", " + ystring);
}
```

Experimenting a little bit then led to this code:

```
public class Draw {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        JPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(myPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        myPanel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                int x = e.getX();
                int y = e.getY();
                String xstring = String.valueOf(x);
                String ystring = String.valueOf(y);
                frame.setTitle(xstring + ", " + ystring);
                ((MyPanel) myPanel).setLastPoint(e);
            }

            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                int x = e.getX();
                int y = e.getY();
                String xstring = String.valueOf(x);
                String ystring = String.valueOf(y);
                frame.setTitle("dragged - " + xstring + ", " + ystring);

                Graphics g = myPanel.getGraphics();
                Point lastPoint = ((MyPanel) myPanel).getLastPoint();
                g.drawLine(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y, e.getX(), e.getY());
                ((MyPanel) myPanel).setLastPoint(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
                g.dispose();
            }
        });
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private Point lastPoint;

    public Point getLastPoint() {
        return lastPoint;
    }

    public void setLastPoint(Point point) {
        lastPoint = point;

    }

    public void setLastPoint(MouseEvent e) {
        lastPoint = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several things here :

When you want to customize the painting of a `Component`, override its `paintComponent` method, don't attempt to get its `Graphics` object with `getGraphics`.

Use `repaint()` to have your `Component` be repainted (i.e `paintComponent` will get called) .

Make your `JFrame` visible only once all the other components have been added.

Here is how your code could be changed:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JPanel {

    private Point lastPoint = new Point();
    private Point currentPoint = new Point();

    public Main() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent e) {
                lastPoint = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        });
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(final MouseEvent e) {

                currentPoint = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                repaint();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawLine(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);

    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setResizable(true);

        frame.getContentPane().add(new Main(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseMoved(final MouseEvent e) {
                int x = e.getX();
                int y = e.getY();
                String xstring = String.valueOf(x);
                String ystring = String.valueOf(y);
                frame.setTitle(xstring + ", " + ystring);
            }
        });
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```